# onClick and onLongClick Selection in Textview

Tags: java, android, selection, onlongclicklistener

I have searched for the answer to this question for a couple of days with no result. When using onClick on a TextView I get the desired result of selecting the word clicked by using:

```
    textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(final View arg0) {
            Spannable span = (Spannable)textView.getText();
            Layout layout = textView.getLayout();

            Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Selection: " + Selection.getSelectionStart(textView.getText().toString()) + Selection.getSelectionEnd(textView.getText().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // returns -1, -1
            Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(), "Selection: " + textView.getSelectionStart() + textView.getSelectionEnd(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //returns -1, -1

            Selection.moveToLeftEdge(span, layout);
            Selection.extendToRightEdge(span, layout);

            final int start = textView.getSelectionStart();
            final int end = textView.getSelectionEnd();
            String string = textView.getText().toString().substring(start, end);                

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(arg0.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Delete: " + string)
            .setMessage("Are you sure? This operation can't be undone!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    deleteItem(start, end);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            })
            .show();
            return true;
        }
    });

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Spannable span = (Spannable)textView.getText();
            Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
            Selection.moveToLeftEdge(span, layout);
            Selection.extendToRightEdge(span, layout);
            writeStrikes(textView.getSelectionStart(), textView.getSelectionEnd());             
        }           
    });
```

When I try using the same code for an onLongClick the selection is -1, -1. If I return false from onLongClick the next selection is where the last should have been. So, the cursor is set when the user releases the long click, after the onLongClick has been called. How do I set the cursor to the position of the long click just before the onLongClick() is called?

Comment: hmmm, can you post more of your code for context?

Comment: Edited to show complete onClick and onLongClick

Comment: Maybe try calling `arg0.performClick()` in `onLongClick()` and using some additional code in `onClick()` to not execute the current code in this case.  I suspect this will initialize the Cursor when the `onClick()` method returns.  When the Cursor is initalized, you should be able to continue with the method and should no longer be getting -1, -1.

Comment: I am very new to this, I have no idea what the "additional" code would be. Any help would be appreciated.